# .NET MVC 4 Invoking Difference Between localhost:port and localhost:port/home/index

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, resources

I am using bootstrap in my .NET MVC 4 project ,I imported bootstrap my project by using NuGet, I have a layout page and i include bootstrap tags in this page, my index page is using layout page and if i call project localhost:portnumber my index page and my bootstrap icons are look good, but i inkove my page like localhost:portnumber/home/index, and my bootstrap icons doesnt look good, it look like a i didnt import bootsrap resources is page and also my images doesnt seen, i cannot find any solution for this problem, if someone help me, thanks

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Doesn't look good is an awful description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be a bit more specific? Doesn't look good is an awful description.

From the sounds of it, you need to specify exactly where the bootstrap resources are, for example: specify the exact location that will be reachable from all pages such as "~/CSS/Bootstrap/", instead of just "CSS/Bootstrap/". You need to ensure that the location is going to the route of your program.

Comment: Thank you Christopher, although i couldnt tell my problem correctly, your solution works. :)